# Unexpected value for length of a vector in R

Tags: r, posixct

I have the character vector below

```
a = c("2009-07-31 18:00:33", "2009-07-31 18:00:38", "2009-07-31 18:00:43",  "2009-07-31 18:00:49", "2009-08-01 01:58:49", "2009-08-01 01:53:16",  "2009-08-01 08:04:13", "2009-08-01 16:16:13")
```

I want to convert this to time objects so I do this:

```
b = strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Why do a and b have different lengths?

```
> length(a)
[1] 8
> length(b)
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `b` has class `POSIXlt`. Arrays of `POSIXlt` dates always return a length of 9,
since the represent a named list of nine vectors:

```
R> class(b)
[1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXlt"

R> unclass(b)
$sec
[1] 33 38 43 49 49 16 13 13
$min
[1]  0  0  0  0 58 53  4 16
$hour
[1] 18 18 18 18  1  1  8 16
$mday
[1] 31 31 31 31  1  1  1  1
$mon
[1] 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7
$year
[1] 109 109 109 109 109 109 109 109
$wday
[1] 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
$yday
[1] 211 211 211 211 212 212 212 212
$isdst
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Class `POSIXct`, which represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of
1970 as a numeric vector, gives you the expected length:

```
R> length(as.POSIXct(a))
[1] 8
R> unclass(as.POSIXct(a))
[1] 1.249e+09 1.249e+09 1.249e+09 1.249e+09 1.249e+09 1.249e+09 1.249e+09
[8] 1.249e+09
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
```

Comment: I get it now.  A vector is not a container in the way I was thinking. Are the times stored in b actually objects?  Can you have a reference to a POSIXlt object?

Comment: I meant a list is not a container in the way I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `?strptime` it converts character strings to class `POSIXlt`. In R there are two types of times: `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct`.
Description is in `?DateTimeClasses`, but to shortcut:

> Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the
>   beginning of 1970 as a numeric
>   vector.
>
> Class "POSIXlt" is a named
>   list of vectors representing 
>   sec    0–61: seconds
>   min    0–59: minutes hour    0–23: hours mday    1–31: day of the month
>   mon    0–11: months after the first of
>   the year. year    Years since 1900.
>   wday    0–6 day of the week, starting
>   on Sunday. yday    0–365: day of the
>   year. isdst    Daylight savings time
>   flag. Positive if in force, zero if
>   not, negative if unknown.

So your `b` is list of 9 vectors, 8-length each.

You can see:

```
sapply(b,length)
```

You could use exact conversion:

```
b_1 = as.POSIXlt(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")
b_2 = as.POSIXct(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")

length(b_1) # 9
length(b_2) # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this FAQ issue is about to change in R 2.11.0:

> 2.11.0 NEW FEATURES
>
> length(POSIXlt) now returns the length
>   of the corresponding abstract
>   timedate-vector rather than always 9
>   (the length of the underlying list
>   structure). (Wish of PR#14073 and
>   PR#10507.)

That's from the December 2 entry of the RSS feed summarising daily changes in the Subversion archive, the [developer page](http://developer.r-project.org) for details about the feed.